# Android NumberPicker setValue does not work with setDisplayedValues

Tags: android-number-picker

I am incrementing values in android NumberPicker by 5, however when I call setValue method, it doesn't seem to work when used together with setDisplayedValues. My code is below, any help is appreciated:

```
String[] numberValues = new String[((maxValue-minValue)/5) + 1];

            int current = 0;
            for (int i = minValue; i <= maxValue; i+= step) {
                numberValues[current] = String.valueOf(i);
                current++;
            }
            setpointPicker.setMinValue(0);
            setpointPicker.setMaxValue(numberValues.length-1);

            setpointPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
            setpointPicker.setDisplayedValues(numberValues);
            setpointPicker.setValue(myValue); // doesn't set the value
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, here is how you setValue when using setDisplayedValues:

```
    for( int i=0; i<numberValues.length ; i++ ) {
                if (numberValues[i].equals(String.valueOf(myIntValue)) {
                    setpointPicker.setValue(i);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Try this instead that 'for':

`int myValue = Arrays.asList(numberValues).indexOf(String.valueOf(myIntValue)));`

and then:
`setpointPicker.setValue(myValue);`